# How to declare value in key:value pair as null if doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this:

```
{
  customer: newCustomer.id,
  coupon: customer.coupon,
  items: [
    {
      plan: customer.plan
     },
  ]
}
```

customer.coupon might not always exist, and when it doesn't exist I need it to be null. It can't just be an empty string because that throws an error. I tried coupon: customer.coupon || null but that didn't work.

Comment: Is this pure javascript? can you provide details on your architecture? Typescript could help you here if that is a possiblity.

Comment: @rjustin sorry I am using vanilla js. it is in backend nodejs

Comment: When you say `I tried coupon: custom.coupon || null` is that `custom` a typo or what you're actually running in your code?

Comment: @JosephCho was type. corrected

Comment: is the **customer** object present ? you might be getting the error because **customer** object is itself null or undefined

Comment: So sending `''` or `null` provides the same response from the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the cleanest solution, but this works as well:

```
if (customer.coupon == undefined) {
  var nullObject = {
    customer: newCustomer.id,
    coupon: null,
    items: [
      {
        plan: customer.plan
       },
    ]
  } 
  return nullObject;
} else {
  var nonNullObject = {
    customer: newCustomer.id,
    coupon: customer.coupon,
    items: [
      {
        plan: customer.plan
       },
    ]
  }
  return nonNullObject;
}
```

Comment: Got it working using this. Except I changed the if statement to if(customer.coupon == ' ') and deleted coupon key from that flow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
  customer: newCustomer.id,
  coupon: customer.coupon || null,
  items: [
    {
      plan: customer.plan
     },
  ]
}
```

JavaScript has the cool ability to take the last value if all previous values are `falsy` (That include `false`, `0`, `null` and others)

So this code:

customer.coupon || null

Will use `customer.coupon`, but it that value is `falsy` the it will take the `null`.

#### UPDATE

I just saw that you stated that this isn't working, what error are you getting?

Comment: There was no error in the console, but stripe returned an error in the callback. It said this:
You passed an empty string for 'coupon'. We assume empty values are an attempt to unset a parameter; however 'coupon' cannot be unset. You should remove 'coupon' from your request or supply a non-empty value.

Comment: Try adding `console.log(obj)` after the object is created and then post the result in your post. That should help us figure out what is failing. It may be that they neither like an empty string nor `null`.

Comment: It may be possible that they don't want the key `coupon` included if there is no coupon. If so then you would need to NOT include that key so @Rudresha Parameshappa's answer may be best.

Comment: it is returning coupon: ' '

Comment: what if you don't send the `coupon` key at all when the value is an empty string. Either delete it, or add it only if it is not an empty string. What happens then?

Answer (score 0):

```
let newCustomer = {"id":1};
let customer = {"coupon":null,"plan":1};

var obj = {
     customer: newCustomer.id,
     coupon: customer.coupon,
     items: [
       {
         plan: customer.plan
        },
     ]
}
console.log(obj);
if(obj.coupon==null)
   delete obj["coupon"]
console.log(obj);
```

and the result from node console I got is

[image]